# Inclusion of computational complexity classes

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I am asked to show that $Space(n^5)$ is contained in $Time(n^{n^5})$. I tried doing it from the definitions, but didn't get anywhere. Is there a trick to this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Computational Complexity: A Modern
Approach page 92 in this pdf. [link](https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the pigeonhole principle. You can show an algorithm using at most $n^5$ space can only be in at most $n^{n^5}$ different configurations and so can only run for that amount of time without entering an infinite loop.